# Background image from CSS not showing up on new site

Tags: html, css, linux, wordpress

I am getting ready to release a WP site and my background image has disappeared. I have the exact same site set up on a separate server that I was using for dev and the image works fine. So the CSS and code are identical. Here is the CSS:

```
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-month .tribe-events-calendar {
    background-image: url("/fitz_originalsize/");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

I read a post suggesting the first line of my CSS should just use background. So I updated my CSS, but this still doesn't work.

```
background:  url("/fitz_originalsize/");
```

I have also gone through all of the sub-directories in Linux Terminal to confirm they are set the same as the original site, 775. Everything is the same.

You can look at a demo site without the image showing up here:

```
http://fitz.asystyou.tech/events/
```

The image that should be showing is here:

```
http://fitz.asystyou.tech/fitz_originalsize/
```

I'm not sure what else could be causing this image to not work. Any suggestions would be a great help.

Comment: that's a permalink in wordpress. in all my other configs, the permalink works in lieu of the actual file name.

Comment: You're probably looking for the photo in the directory of your theme, not your website (you specified the image was in the root directory by the url) so perhaps try using `../` in your path name to navigate to the image. Also, do any errors (404 etc) appear in the console?

Comment: I tried the leading dots and still could not get this to work. I decided to take a direct link to the image and see if that would work and it does. I replace /fitz_originalsize/ with /wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2019/05/fitz_originalSize.jpg and my image is displaying as expected. That is not the ideal solution but it works. So for now that is what I am going to use. We have a launch scheduled for this week so I'll circle back to this after that launch and see what caused this issue. It could be an update in  WordPress, Linux or PHP that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the full path to my image:

```
background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2019/05/fitz_originalSize.jpg")
```

This doesn't answer the question to why this started happening in the first place. But the version of WordPress the new site is on is different than where I did the development. There is a chance the version of PHP is newer also. I think something changed in one of those environments that broke this, but for now I have a working solution in place.